# Odds vs Odds ratio in GLM function

Tags: r, regression, logistic, multiple-regression

If I estimate a model with logistic function:

```
glm(Yi~Xi,Di, data=data, family=binomial(link="logit") )
```

where `Di` is dummy.

The estimated coefficients are: (Intercept) =0.9, Xi=2.3, Di=-0.33

If I exponentiated the estimated coefficients returned by this regression, are these considered odds or odds ratios?

Answer (score 1):

The term `(Intercept)` is an odds for the response `Yi` when `Di`=0 and `Xi`=0. Depending the encoding, the other term(s) will represent odds ratios for the response for the specific (non-zero) levels of `Di` compared to 0. If `Xi` is continuous, the odds ratio is a ratio fo odds for groups differing by 1 unit in `Xi`.

Comment: added a clarification

Comment: It shouldn't matter to know what the coefs actually are.